# Is it the first Line on a new Page?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

how can i do a PrintWhenExpression in iReport that shows the according TextField only:

1) The first Record

2) the first Record of a new Page

I´m a little bit confused with the built in Variables

BR

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
$V{PAGE_COUNT}.intValue() == 1
```